# Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <service> even if there were no services in my AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, android-studio

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

There are no `<services` in my app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I also looked for each `AndroidManifest.xml` file and they also don't have any `<service` element, so why am I getting this error?

There are no errors in my merged manifest tab, however, the first manifest has two `<receiver` and I've already added `android:exported` property manually in them.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are using a library that has a service. Did you check your merged manifest? There is a sub-tab for that in the manifest editor in Android Studio.

Answer (score 9):

In `app` -> `src` -> `main` -> `AndroidManifest.xml` you need to explicitly add the Tag of `android:exported="true"` in each `<Activity>` under `<Application>`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Eynetic">
    <activity android:name=".Splash_Screen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

See the Activity Tag in the code...

```
<activity android:name=".Splash_Screen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:exported="true">
```

Currently i am doing it with each activity as that was the error given by Android studio but maybe there is a better way to add it only once somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:exported = false` pr `android:exported = true` in your own manifest file and compile the code. I hope this should solve you issue. As adding manually in notification will not work.

Comment: Where to add that?

Comment: Put this below MainActivity tag where you declare in manifest file

Comment: My `MainActivity` already has this property set. I think you didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: If this is not working then try to  set Target SDK to 30. Compile and rebuild project.

Comment: Add Manifest screen shot how one can understand what is there in manifest.